# How to describe points given a matrix and its determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

[image: the question]

Hi, I'm confused where to even start with this problem. Any help would be appreciated. What do the points have to do with the equation at all? I know if we plug in [a1, a2] for [x1, x2] for example, the matrix would have two rows with the same values, so the determinant would be zero. But how can I relate that to all the points? How are the points related to each other? Are they all equal to each other?

Thanks

Comment: An equation $f(x_1,x_2)=0$ is a restriction. Some pairs of numbers $(x_1,x_2)$ will satisfy it, some won't. They want you to find all pairs of points that do satisfy it. Pairs of number can be seen as coordinates of points in the plane. So, if you paint black the point which coordinates satisfy the equation you get a picture. Describing that picture is a common way to describe the set of solutions of an equation.

Comment: For that particular equation one key idea is to check if the points $(a_1,a_2)$, $(b_1,b_2)$, and $(c_1,c_2)$ satisfy that equation (They do). The resulting figure is going to be a circle passing through those three points. Another idea that you could use is to expand the determinant along the first column.

Comment: If you think of expanding the determinant on the first column, you get some real numbers (constants)  and determinant coming out as $A(x^2 + y^2) + B x + C y + D.$ Even without finding out the precise contants, completing the square says that we have one of:  (I)the empty set  (II) a single point (III) a circle by setting the polynomial to zero. As @blueink points out, it is a genuine circle; you also said that  setting $ (x,y) = (a_1,a_2)$ would give determinant zero,  same for $ (x,y) = (b_1,b_2).$ Note that if the three fixed points are collinear, the "circle" is actually a straight line

Comment: Worthwhile exercise to get you started: if the three fixed points are collinear, why is my coefficient $A$ become equal to zero? Note that $A$ is (plus or minus) the three by three upper right determinant.

Comment: Oh, I was writing $x = x_1,  \; \; y = x_2$

Comment: How do you know that the points are collinear?